# What type should I use for binary representation of C enum?

Tags: c, enums, binary, representation

As I know C enum is unsigned integer, but this may vary by implementation.
What type should I use for the enum in binary representation?

*PS
'binary representation' means byte-array. I want to serialize enum values to socket to inter-operate with other programs.

Comment: `enum` is an integer type; it's not unsigned.  What do you mean by "enum in binary representation"?  Can you provide an example?  Do you mean you want a type suitable for, say, bitmasks?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Note: _The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer
constant expression that has a value representable as an int._ Assuming `enum`s are `unsigned int` is a not correct.

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry for unclarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the compiler to use an `int` to represent an `enum` type, or a `long` if an `int` is not sufficient to hold all the values of the `enum`.

If you know that all your `enum` values can be represented by an `int`, then you can safely use `int` as the binary representation of your `enum` values.

Comment: You're right. I have to know exact spec of my compiler. I opened a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509552/whats-the-data-type-of-c-enum-of-clang-compiler

Comment: Hm, I don't think that it may be `long` for that reason, but maybe the specification allows it to be `long`. All enumeration type constants are by definition `int`, so `int` will always be able to hold all values.

Answer (score 1):

As enums are just fancy ways to set integers, you should go for an integer type big enough to store all you enum values. Normally, a char should suffice and then there are no serialization issues. But I'd go for a short or a long instead. When serializing, I'd use `ntohs/htons` or `ntohl/htonl` (see their man pages) to always make sure the serialization is in network byte order and the deserialization is in host byte order.

Answer (score 0):

How about `xdr` - library routines for external data representation?

Reinventing the wheel rarely produces something better.